# An anime or cartoon with Magical Artifacts that grant powers

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

Should have come out in mid or late 2000s,

Plot starts off with main character boy leaving his grandfather to go off somewhere, also being gifted a necklace by grandfather that belonged to his dead parents.

Meets with a organization that seeks out these magical artifacts to protect them from misuse, has a run in with a girl from this organization, she doesn’t acknowledge him and believes he is useless, tests him and is proven wrong.

Also remember distinctly an episode where a artifact they find causes them to time travel back to when the main character’s parents were still alive taking care of the younger version main character, and they have interaction.

The world of the show was a mix of medieval and modern, had primitive towns and aspects but also technology and airships

Main character was part of a 3 person team, with a girl and another boy. They were based in a flying Carrier/Blimp-like airship.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you remember what power his necklace granted him?  Where did you see this?  What was the animation style?

Comment: I think I remember the powers primarily being elemental? The girl I believe had wind powers, animation style was similar to Mysterious Joker(anime). I think I remember watching it on The Hub.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magi-Nation_(TV_series) had a grandfather who gifts a magic ring, but the other details don't quite match up otherwise.

Comment: Actually might have seen it on Jetix, and yeah looked into Magi-nation, not the one. Extra detail actually the world of the show was a mix of medieval and modern, had primitive towns and aspects but also technology and airships.

Comment: I added that to the question. You can [edit] in further details as you recall them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was *[Tai Chi Chasers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tai_Chi_Chasers)*

[image: Title image of Tai Chi Chasers]

> After a strange and devastating attack on his home, a young boy named Rai is shocked to discover he is a secret descendent of the Tigeroids (Korean: 호족): an ancient race of peaceful beings locked in a struggle with the ruthless and cunning Dragonoids (Korean: 용족). In a parallel universe called Suhn, the Tigeroids and Dragonoids are battling furiously to recover 500 lost Tai Chi characters. Whoever retrieves these precious and potent symbols will possess the ultimate power to rule their realm... and destroy their enemies. As Rai hones his innate Tai Chi skills to fight the Dragonoids, he must find the lost Tai Chi and battle to become one of the champion Tai Chi Chasers!

It wasn't artifacts; it was magical cards, a team of 5 not 3. Also, there was no necklace, oddly, and it was Korean apparently (on *The CW 4kids*). I literally hunted channels and programming down to finally find it. Episode 20 is when they get send back in time to meet his dead parents.

### Promo

Answer (score 2):

This is the one you're looking for: ***[Huntik: Secrets & Seekers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huntik:_Secrets_%26_Seekers)*** (2009-2011).

From Wikipedia:

> *Huntik: Secrets & Seekers* is an Italian animated television series created by Iginio Straffi, the creator of *Winx Club*. It was produced by Rainbow, a studio co-owned by Straffi and Viacom. The series is about four adventurers who are part of a group called the Huntik Foundation. The Huntik team is led by their top operative Dante Vale. Every episode takes place in a different historical city and features magical elements inspired by European mythology. The characters are designed in a style that combines Japanese anime with Western animation.

> The series follows Lok Lambert as he uncovers the secret legacy of his missing father. His father, Eathon, was a member of the Huntik Foundation and a part of a secret world of magic users known as Seekers and creatures known as Titans. On his mission to uncover what happened to his father, Lok is joined by Dante Vale, Sophie Casterwill, Zhalia Moon, and a talking Titan called Cherit.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. When answering a story identification question though, it's helpful to explain the ways in which a given story matches the one described in the question, rather than only providing a title. In this case, the OP also marked [JudKevin's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/137455/judkevin) as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), as denoted by the green tick next to that answer, which indicates that they believed that answer was correct.

Comment: It's worth noting that we encourage partial and technically correct answers with good details, even if they're later proven not right, as they may help people in the future. We're a bit more hazy on adding them after an answer is accepted. Either way, you do need to have matching details.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots A URL + "This is the one you looking for" is hardly a "partial and technically correct answer."  You might want to check the context of a comment before suggesting the review was deficient.

Comment: @DavidW: As I noted, we do need the details. But I occasionally see people delete good answers because "the question already has an accepted answer" and I wanted to proactively discourage that.